# Using RTK query with modules structure and calling multiple apis in one component overrides the previous previous url and values

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using RTK query with a modular structure. So I don't need to write endpoints per url. The problem is if I call two api call in one components the recent call with override the previous one.

JobformContainer.jsx

```
import clients from '../../redux/modules/clients';
import yupSchemaService from '../../services/yupSchemaService';
import dataService from '../../services/dataService';
import { fetchAutoCompleteData } from '../../services/autoCompleteService';
import jobs from '../../redux/modules/jobs';
  const {
    data: jobData,
    error: jobError,
    isFetching: jobLoading,
  } = jobs.list().useJobDetailQuery({
    params: { id: params.jobId },
    extendedPath: apiUrls.getJob(),
    skip: !params.jobId,
  });

  const {
    data: clientsList,
    isFetching: isLoadingClient,
    error: errorClient,
    isSuccess: successClient,
  } = clients
    .list()
    .useListQuery(
      { params: '', extendedPath: apiUrls.getClientListing() },
      { refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true },
    );

  const [createJob, createJobData] = jobs.form().useCreateMutation();
```

Client.js for clients api calls

```
import form from '../apiService/form';
import list from '../apiService/list';
import destroy from '../apiService/destroy';

const clients = {};
clients.list = () => list('/rest/clients', 'clients');
clients.form = () => form('/rest/clients', 'clients');
clients.delete = () => destroy('/rest/clients/delete', 'clients');

export default clients;
```

jobs.js for jobs module api calls

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import form from '../apiService/form';
import list from '../apiService/list';

const jobs = {};
jobs.list = () => list('/rest/jobs', 'job');
jobs.form = () => form('/rest/jobs', 'job');

export default jobs;
```

list.js is code splitting of rtk where I inject endpoints

```
import { authHeader } from '../../constants/authenticationHeader';
import { baseSliceWithTags } from '../baseSlice';

const list = (path, module) => {
  const listApi = baseSliceWithTags.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => {
      return {
        list: builder.query({
          query: (payload) => {
            return {
              url: path + (payload?.extendedPath || ''),
              method: 'get',
              csrf: authHeader(),
              params: payload?.params,
            };
          },
          providesTags: [module],
        }),
        detail: builder.query({
          query: (payload) => ({
            url: path + (payload?.extendedPath || ''),
            method: 'get',
            csrf: authHeader(),
            params: payload?.params,
          }),
          providesTags: [module],

          keepUnusedDataFor: 0,
        }),
      };
    },
    overrideExisting: true,
  });
  return listApi;
};
export default list;
```

[Network calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPQ2X.png)

As in network all calls are /clients module call even though I have called the jobs module but it gets called with clients parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoints need unique names for that api, so `clientList` and `formList`.

To be clear: you are **injecting into the same api**. This is not giving you new hooks every time, if you inject a new endpoint with the same name, it overrides the internal config and returns the same hook.

As you are doing it, they overwrite each other. That is also why you are getting error messages unless you activate `overrideExisting: true`.

Essentially, RTK Query was warning you that you should not do it, but you did it anyways ;)

Comment: So, I have to make all endpoints unique and for that I have to write each point for every module and I have around 200-300 apis. It'll be alot of work. Is there anyway to make generic endpoint which can be used with multiples module other than code generation?
Thanks alot @phry for quick reply :)

Comment: I would check if there is not an OpenAPI spec for your api as you can just go automatic code generation from that. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-generation
Also, you can still use your code but just make sure the names are unique. So instead of `list: builder.query({` write `[module+"List"]: builder.query({` - that way you generate a `clientsList` and a `jobsList`.